# How to navigate from storyboard to xib file in swift?

Tags: swift, navigation, storyboard, xib

Today I faced with other problem again. I want to navigate from my storyboard to xib file when viewDidLoad. It navigated but i got black screen.

My xib file: TutorialScreen.xib

Class that control xib file: TutorialScreenViewController.swift

My code in TutorialScreenViewController.swift:

```
 class TutorialScreenViewController : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    mainView = UIView()
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

convenience init() {
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}


}
```

Code in Other Class When viewDidLoad:

```
let tutorialScreen = TutorialScreenViewController(nibName: "TutorialScreen", bundle: nil) as TutorialScreenViewController

        self.navigationController?.presentViewController(tutorialScreen, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Here is what I got:

[image: I got this black screen]

My TutorialScreen.xib:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found out something wrong that i did. And here is what i edit:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
mainView = UIView()
super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

After edit:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    mainView = UIView()
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil , bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

That's it !!!!!!